# Tableview bouncing only one side top side

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scrollview

I have one `UITableView` and i want to `set bouncing only one side top side.` but i could not solve this problem . see this video link and give me solution for that . any suggestion is appreciate and accepted.

Here 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qztsfkqoxuy4aaj/question.mov?dl=0

Here is my tableview info.

[image]

Comment: A bounce at top and bottom is standard iOS behaviour - preventing this may seem "wrong" to the user.

Comment: but i need that kind of flow in project so i need to develop app like that .

Comment: @AshleyMills i need batter solution i have to set all tableview like this when i got only single row then also.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Hems3112/efd2d10a83a56b401ef0256deca7774a

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the  method `scrollViewDidScroll` to check the content offset of the tableview's scrollview.  check if the user is trying to scroll beyond the bottom bounds of the table view. if so, scroll back to end of tableview. this will not limit bottom bounce but will scroll back so quickly that user will not notice bottom bounces.

```
   - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
            [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)];
        }
    }
```

///UPDATE-- If Tableview's content size will be less than its frame, above code may not work.
you can use following in that case:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if(scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollView.frame.size.height)
    {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) {
       [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }
    }
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >=  0)
    {
         [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, 0)];
    }
}
```

Comment: let me try this one .

Comment: Using this answer, if you only have one row in the table, that row will be positioned at the bottom of the screen, and the delegate method is called repeatedly as the tableview tries to scroll itself back into position

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Try adding a log statement at the start of this method - I think you'll find it's called repeatedly

Comment: @AshleyMills ok wait

Comment: @AshleyMills ye its continuously call this method when i scroll my tableview. but with this solution my problem solve.

Comment: Does it call the method continuously when you stop scrolling? You should also check what happens when your table only has less that a whole screen of rows

Comment: @AshleyMills ya its continuously call that method when i scroll to bottom side and in my case all time i have to display at least 7 row , so that i did not check now. but letter on when i need then i check this issue also

Comment: @AshleyMills did you give me batter solution ?

Comment: :) guys, Have updated my answer to handle the issue pointed by  @AshleyMills

Comment: bool bouncingBottom = false; @iOS_devloper why you declare this bool variable ?

Comment: sorry..Let me remove that..I has some other logic in mind..Forgot to remove that.

Comment: Thanks  @SathiReddy

Comment: i have added content inset of 84 on top so it is scrolling that much in iphone 6 and 6 plus how to stop that?